# How to give my own id to the container of High Chart in Yii

Tags: php, yii, highcharts

I'm using [high-chart](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/highcharts/) extension, but I don't know how to give `ID` to the container, now getting random id's like `yw11,yw12` etc., How to give my own ids to the container like `graph1, graph2` etc.,

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Change widget id container as states in [this line](https://github.com/miloschuman/yii-highcharts/blob/master/highcharts/HighchartsWidget.php#L65).
2. Set directly id of container:

   ```
   $this->Widget('ext.highcharts.HighchartsWidget',array(
       'options' =>array(   
           'chart' => array('renderTo' => $id),                                 
           'title' => array('text' => 'title'),
           'yAxis' => array(
               'title' => array('text' => 'y-values'),                           
           )
       )        
   ));
   ```

Answer (score 0):

set id to highcharts in yii2 :

```php
  echo Highcharts::widget([
    'id' => 'YOUR-CUSTOM-ID',
    'options' => [
        'chart' => [
            'type' => 'column',
            'margin' => [60, 10, 40, 40],
        ],
        'title' => [
            'text' => 'Symmetrical Distribution',
            'x' => 25
        ],
        'subtitle' => [
            'text' => 'Fisher\'s Iris Data: Sepal Width',
            'x' => 25,
        ],
        'legend' => [
            'enabled' => false,
        ],
        'credits' => [
            'enabled' => false,
        ],
        'tooltip' => [
        ],
        'scripts' => [
            'highcharts-more', // enables supplementary chart types (gauge, arearange, columnrange, etc.)
            'modules/exporting', // adds Exporting button/menu to chart
            'themes/grid'        // applies global 'grid' theme to all charts
        ],
        'plotOptions' => [
            'series' => [
                'pointPadding' => 0,
                'groupPadding' => 0.5,
                'borderColor' => 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)',
                'color' => '#434348',
            ]
        ],
        'xAxis' => [
            'title' => [
                'text' => 'Sepal Width (cm)'
            ]
        ],
        'yAxis' => [
            'title' => [
                'text' => ''
            ]
        ],
        'series' => [
            [
                'name' => 'Distribution',
                'data' => [[2.1, 4], [2.3000000000000003, 7], [2.5, 13], [2.7, 23], [2.9000000000000004, 36], [3.1, 24], [3.3000000000000003, 18], [3.5000000000000004, 10], [3.7000000000000006, 9], [3.9000000000000004, 3], [4.1, 2], [4.300000000000001, 1]]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]);
```